# How do I find the location of tokens in a quanteda token object?

Tags: r, token, quanteda

I have created a quanteda tokens object from a plain text file, and selected the specific words I seek using

```
tokens_select(truePdfAnnualReports.toks, unlist(strategicKeywords.list), padding = TRUE)
```

To maintain the specific token sequence found in the original text file.  I now wish to assign token position number (absolute and relative) to the tokens selected by the function.  How do I assign position numbers for the tokens selected by the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `kwic()`, not `tokens_select()`.  I created a reproducible example answer using the built-in `data_corpus_inaugural` below.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

toks <- tokens(tail(data_corpus_inaugural, 10))
keywords <- c("nuclear", "security")

# form a data.frame from kwic() results
kw <- kwic(toks, keywords, window = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# for illustration
kw[10:14, ]
##         docname from   to pre  keyword post  pattern
## 10  1985-Reagan 2385 2385     security      security
## 11    1989-Bush 2149 2149     security      security
## 12 1997-Clinton  259  259     security      security
## 13 1997-Clinton 1660 1660      nuclear       nuclear
## 14    2001-Bush  872  872     Security      security
```

Now, to get the relative positions, we can do a little **dplyr** magic once we get the total tokens lengths and divide:

```r
doc_lengths <- data.frame(
  docname = docnames(toks),
  toklength = ntoken(toks)
)

# the answer
answer <- dplyr::left_join(kw, doc_lengths) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    from_relative = from / toklength,
    to_relative = to / toklength
  )
## Joining, by = "docname"
head(answer)
##       docname from   to pre  keyword post  pattern toklength from_relative
## 1 1985-Reagan 2005 2005     security      security      2909     0.6892403
## 2 1985-Reagan 2152 2152     security      security      2909     0.7397731
## 3 1985-Reagan 2189 2189      nuclear       nuclear      2909     0.7524923
## 4 1985-Reagan 2210 2210      nuclear       nuclear      2909     0.7597112
## 5 1985-Reagan 2245 2245      nuclear       nuclear      2909     0.7717429
## 6 1985-Reagan 2310 2310     security      security      2909     0.7940873
##   to_relative
## 1   0.6892403
## 2   0.7397731
## 3   0.7524923
## 4   0.7597112
## 5   0.7717429
## 6   0.7940873
```

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158274/ken-benoit! That worked splendidly. Any way to run that process via parallel, or something similar?

Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear it. Pls accept the answer then. `kwic()` is already parallelized. You can get faster joins than from dplyr using **data.table**, if that helps.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks for letting me know kwic() was already parallelized. I didn't know. The joins are not an issue for me, but good to know kwic() runs on multiple cores.